# How To Filter Rows Based On A List From Another Sheet? (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Excel, it is quite easy to filter rows based on a list from another sheet. But, Google Sheets does not have an advanced filter option. It therefore is not possible to filter a column by list range and criteria range in the same way that one would in Excel. So, how do you filter rows based on a list from another sheet in Google Sheets?

**Worksheet to Be Filtered**

[image: Worksheet]

**Worksheet with Filter List**

[image: Filter List]

Comment: Screenshots added.

Comment: After filtering, the sheet should not display any rows that contain values for farm_a OR farm_b that are not listed in the bottom sheet (via =customer!A2:A3).

Comment: Note: The sample sheet with the list contains only two values. Obviously, that would be easy to filter manually. So, assume both sheets contain many more rows  than the samples (e.g. =customer!A2:A5000)

Comment: BTW: I tried =query(farm!A2:C7, "where A = customer!A2:A3 ",1) followed by =query(farm!A2:C7, "where B = customer!A2:A3 ",1). But, that did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Select A1:C11
- Create a Filter
- Select A1 Filter dropdown
- Custom Formula:

  ```
  =OR(IFERROR(MATCH(A2,customer!A$2:A$3,0),0),IFERROR(MATCH(B2,customer!A$2:A$3,0),0))
  ```
- Both A2 and B2(HGFD and MNCD and all the respective rows below) are checked against `customer!A$2:A$3`. If A or B contain anything from the Customer list,It'll be shown. A2 and B2 are representative of the whole A and B column.
- Alternatively,

  ```
  =FILTER(A1:C11,IFERROR(MATCH(A1:A11,customer!A$2:A$3,0))+IFERROR(MATCH(B1:B11,customer!A$2:A$3,0)))
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes more sense than the query function. I needed to run it as an AND not the OR. But, that was the only change.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [guide](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4113-excel-filter-based-on-list-selection.html) I used that worked for me in Excel:

> 1. Select a blank cell next to the rows you want to filter, and enter this formula `=COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6, A2)`, and press Enter, then
>      drag the auto fill handle down to apply this formula to the cells.
> 2. Select the column including the formulas, and then click Data > Filter to apply Filter function.
> 3. Click the Filter icon in the formula column, only check `1` in the drop down list.
> 4. Click OK. Now the rows have been filter based on the list in Sheet2.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1

```
=FILTER(Sheet!A2:C,
        COUNTIF(Filter!A2:A, Sheet!A2:A) + COUNTIF(Filter!A2:A, Sheet!B2:B))
```

Option 2

```
=QUERY(Sheet!A2:C, 
       "select * where A matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,Filter!A2:A)&"' 
                    or B matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,Filter!A2:A)&"'")
```

Option 1 is using COUNTIF as explained [here](https://www.spreadsheetclass.com/filter-based-on-a-list-in-google-sheets/). The `+` is acting as a `OR`.

Option 2 is using QUERY function, with keyword `matches` that uses regular expression `keyword1|keyword2` where `|` is acting as `OR`.